# (JavaScript) Why can't I add method to `object.__proto__` with arrow function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
function Circle(radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = ()=>{
        console.log(`draw`);
    }
}; 

const p = new Circle(12);

p.__proto__.showRadAnony = ()=>{
    return this.radius;
}

p.__proto__.showRadNorm = function(){
    return this.radius;
}   
   
console.log(p.showRadNorm());
console.log(p.showRadAnony());
```

I add `showRadAnony` method to `Circle.prototype` by initiate it with anonymous function while add `showRadNorm` too which does same thing with `showRadAnony` but initiated it by arrow function.

When I run the code, `showRadNorm` shows 12 in console. while `showRadNorm` returns `undefined`

Is it because arrow function is new feature of es6?